# http error when uploading media file to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, http, upload

I have tried both Wordpress v3.5 and v3.6, and everytime I upload a file via the media tab, it gives me an http error. This is the console output (F12):

```
POST http://asksomeone.co.za/Ginellis/wordpress/wp-admin/async-upload.php 404 (Not Found) 

load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery,utils,plupload,plupload-html5,plupload-flash,plupload-silverlight,plupload-html4,plupload-handlers&ver=3.5.1:8
    G load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery,utils,plupload,plupload-html5,plupload-flash,plupload-silverlight,plupload-html4,plupload-handlers&ver=3.5.1:8
    B load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery,utils,plupload,plupload-html5,plupload-flash,plupload-silverlight,plupload-html4,plupload-handlers&ver=3.5.1:8
    w load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery,utils,plupload,plupload-html5,plupload-flash,plupload-silverlight,plupload-html4,plupload-handlers&ver=3.5.1:8
    (anonymous function) load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery,utils,plupload,plupload-html5,plupload-flash,plupload-silverlight,plupload-html4,plupload-handlers&ver=3.5.1:8
    g.extend.trigger load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery,utils,plupload,plupload-html5,plupload-flash,plupload-silverlight,plupload-html4,plupload-handlers&ver=3.5.1:7
    s load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery,utils,plupload,plupload-html5,plupload-flash,plupload-silverlight,plupload-html4,plupload-handlers&ver=3.5.1:7
    g.extend.start load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery,utils,plupload,plupload-html5,plupload-flash,plupload-silverlight,plupload-html4,plupload-handlers&ver=3.5.1:7
    (anonymous function) load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery,utils,plupload,plupload-html5,plupload-flash,plupload-silverlight,plupload-html4,plupload-handlers&ver=3.5.1:12
    g.extend.trigger load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery,utils,plupload,plupload-html5,plupload-flash,plupload-silverlight,plupload-html4,plupload-handlers&ver=3.5.1:7
    o load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery,utils,plupload,plupload-html5,plupload-flash,plupload-silverlight,plupload-html4,plupload-handlers&ver=3.5.1:8
    E.onchange load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery,utils,plupload,plupload-html5,plupload-flash,plupload-silverlight,plupload-html4,plupload-handlers&ver=3.5.1:8
```

Why is this doing it? I have several wordpress sites on that domain(in different directories) and they all upload fine...but when uploading a file from media or from any theme uploader, it gives me that error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you found any resolution?  This is happening to me when I upload a file over 1mb.  I have php.ini max post and upload to 64mb. memory_limit at 128m.

Comment: I have Wordpress 4.6.1, memory_limit 1024M, post_max_size,max_uploaded_size to 25 M, Happen random the same set of images when size > 550KB~